# Backup sql server logins and users

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Need to backup Database Users and Logins for particular database from prod server and restore it to Dev server ?hw can i proceed

Comment: Can you backup your Production db and restore it on Development db?

Comment: Yes i can do but only constraint is NO-DATA must to be backed up.
Data must be flushed and Rest all the Users, logins, Triggers,tables,constraints,views, stored proc needs to be backuped and restore it in DEV server .can u assist me in this regards ?

Answer (score 0):

[sql-server-2005-backup-restore-and-orphaned-users](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2008/10/28/sql-server-2005-backup-restore-and-orphaned-users/)

**EDIT:**

In this case, can you restore your production db on development db and flush all data from tables? If you can do this then use following script to do this.

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
```

[Empty all tables.](http://riteshshah.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/empty-all-table-or-delete-all-data-from-all-table-by-sp_msforeachtable-in-sql-server-2005/)

**A better link:** [SQL Server Delete all data - Delete the data without resetting the identities - Delete the data and reset the identities](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/CommentView,guid,933a7883-b5d2-4e41-9662-589948702b35.aspx)

Comment: HI Kashif, thnks for ur link but i have 140 users , how to use in that case any idea ??